# React inline-CSS: avoid huge duplication in DOM elements

Tags: css, reactjs

After some research and reads, I found out that the community is quickly moving to a more component-scoped CSS in order to avoid global variables definition using classic CSS stylesheets (https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js).

I'm currently working on a data-table based project where I need to render many tabular elements using `div` as cells. This leads me to a huge duplication on inline style and a not-so-sexy DOM:

[image]

I don't want to use any library (Radium, Aphrodite, styledcomponents, CSS Modules) to keep the project "vanilla" and reduce my dependencies (more a request than a wish...).

Is there a best-practice to avoid this huge mess in the DOM?

Maybe, is there a way to generate a class name "on demand" and apply it to the rendered component?

Comment: Welcome to inline styles in React.  It looks like garbage.  It offends my every sensibility as someone who spent years writing meticulous CSS sheets to avoid this problem.  It makes the element inspector damn near unusable.  But ... this is what the community wants these days, so live with it - or don't.

Comment: So why do you use inline styles and not classNames? Btw, I am totally disagree about community wants inline styles, where did you get this? My suggestion is to use `styled-components`, what do you want to save by not using helpful library?

Comment: To be honest, I enjoy using CSS-in-JS for the all the goodies of using JS to create styles. The only problem is in the reduced readability of the DOM (which is not a user problem anyway) and the undesired complexity in achieving `:hover`, `:focus` etc...

I'm not trying to save anything avoiding using a helpful library. But I like to keep things vanilla as much as I can (and this is why I'm asking this question).